# How to load multiple lists in a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I currently work on a Windows Forms application and I have 3 lists of data and I want to add every list to a column of a datagrid. Is there a way how I can do this.

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Globals.pathNotifFile);
        var dates = doc.Descendants("Date");
        var hours = doc.Descendants("Time");
        var message = doc.Descendants("Message");
        var hoursCollection = new List<String>();
        var dateCollection = new List<String>();
        var messageCollection = new List<String>();

        foreach (var date in dates)
        {
            dateCollection.Add(date.Value);
        }

        foreach (var hour in hours)
        {
            hoursCollection.Add(hour.Value);
        }

        foreach (var messages in message)
        {
            messageCollection.Add(messages.Value);
        }

        return Tuple.Create(hoursCollection,dateCollection, messageCollection);
    }
```

Comment: can you give a image how you want to display?

Comment: https://s7.postimg.org/hsuf9123f/Untitled.png

Comment: I think your question should be **How to bind Tuple<List<string>> to DataGridView**, and I think that is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this task is to build one object which contains your three datapoints. For example:

```
public class MyGridDateTime
{
  public string Hour{get;set;}

  public string Date{get;set;}

  public string Message{get;set;}
}

public void InitalizeGrid()
{
   List<MyGridDateTime> list = new List<MyGridDateTime>();
   int i = 0;
   foreach (string hour in hoursCollection)
   {
      list.Add(new MyGridDateTime {Hour = hour, Date = dateCollection[i], Message = messageCollection[i]};
      i++;
   }

   grid.DataSource = list;
}
```

Note this only works if all of your Lists contain similiar amount of data. Else you need to update this a bit to become string.empty instead of Exception if your Lists are not of the same size.